# UPDATE optimization for SQL Server locking

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, locking

With regard to how SQL Server locks data, are there any benefits to updating a single column in a table row compared to updating the entire row?

From what I understand, SQL Server cannot lock data at a more granular level than a table row. For example, given a row with columns A,B,C,D,E where A is the primary key, an update cannot change columns B/C, while another update modifies columns D/E, correct?

Presuming my assumptions about SQL Server locking are correct, can I extrapolate that there are no performance benefits to be had from updating individual columns in a row instead of updating the entire row?

Example scenario to further illustrate the question in more detail: Given a table(product) with columns: uuid (primary key), length, width, height, weight

Scenario **#1**

```
ProductDAO.updateLength(Long uuid, float length);
ProductDAO.updateWidth(Long uuid, float weight)
```

Scenario **#2**

```
ProductDAO.update(Long uuid, float length, float width, float height, float weight)
```

**Primary Question**:
In the context of preventing deadlocks and maximizing UPDATE query throughput, are Scenarios #1 & #2 effectively the same, or are there good reasons to create more granular update functions?

Obviously, scenario #2 has the benefit of involving significantly less code to test/maintain as we can use a single function for most of the updates which will allow us to treat the object's repository like an in-memory collection of those objects.

Comment: Yes a row lock is the most granular lock. your scenario #2 is preferred, it "cost" the same whether you are updating a single column or multiple columns. The smallest amount of data Sql server reads or writes is an 8k data page.

Comment: I think it depends on the index of the table as well, assuming you have no index or triggers that involves the columns than #2 should be preferred.

Comment: An index is beneficial for locating the row(s) to update, I can't see how it would have any relevance whether 1 or 2 row updates are done - other than two updates require a second seek or scan to be repeated for no benefit.

Comment: As it is most of the time the answer is "it depends".  There are many factors would impact this.  It depends on what indexes are on the table,  whether a clustered key is being updated and a bunch of other factors.  


Generally, assuming you need to update more than one column, it is best to update them all at once.  Performance wise it is best to check that you are actually changing values before updating.  I've seen lots of procs that update rows for no reason and that often has a high performance impact.

Comment: @Stu Columns that are updated get the relevant index locked also. If you don't update any columns in an index then that index will not be locked at all

Comment: Indeed yes, which if the update of two columns present in one or more indexes is split into two separate operations would have a detrimental effect with locks repeatedly being aquired/released.

Answer (score 0):

Your understood has incorrect words that reveal some misundestood...

As every RDBMS, the minimum lock is one row. But if there is many indexes containing the updated value of the concerned column, all the indexes will be locked too.
This is to guarantee the consistency of the database and its acesses.

Updating individually and iteratively many columns of the same record with many UPDATEs instead of updating the the entire targeted columns in a single UPDATE will be worst of all, because the locks will be established and released for every single UPDATE, resulting of :

1 - A time consumming problem

2 - A possible loose of update transactionnal anomaly

For the least remark, while you are executings those many UPDATES, some other user, can also do an update of the same row and one of the same column as you, so you won't finally have the correct values for the row !